# Remove .html extension in url

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

Today I tried to remove html file extension from my website, for example:
`example.com/page.html` to `example.com/page`

I watched some tutorials, but nothing seems to work...
I created `.htaccess` file in root directory
Copied code (also tried different ones):

```htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It didn't work when I opened my website as file, with Live Server (VS Code extension) or actual website (hosted on Replit)

Any idea, why it doesn't work? Any help appreciated...
See [whole repository](https://github.com/yungcypo/Website)

Edit: Someone said, I have to remove `.html` file extension. I get error that the file is not found

Comment: Try removing the `.html` extension from the files

Comment: `.htaccess` is only used by some apache-based web servers. Not by any web server. And not (to my knowledge) by vscode live server, and maybe not by replit neither.

Comment: As @PA. states above. However, you don't use `.htaccess` to actually "remove" the file extension anyway. I notice in your repo that all your links still contain the `.html` extension in the HTML source. You need to actually modify your internal links in the underlying HTML to "remove" the `.html` extension. You then use `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the request to _append_ the `.html` file extension in order to serve the correct file - which is what your rule above is doing.

Comment: (_Aside:_ You can later implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to "remove" the file extension, but that is only for SEO if changing an established URL structure that has already been indexed/linked to. It should not be necessary to implement a redirect for your site to function.)

Answer (score 1):

Yo should do it in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
As someone said, `.htaccess` file doesn't work on Replit. I've done following:

1. Made folder for every `.html` file
2. Moved that file inside of the folder I made
3. Renamed the file to `index.html`